# How to write an algorithm that filters out fake names?

Tags: facebook, google-plus

As you probably know Google+ and Facebook disallow user to create account with a "fake" name.

What is behind? How you can suspect a name to be unreal?

Why "Paul Smith" is more real than "John John"?

Can it be statistics on existing user full names?

Edit (after this question was closed): I think this question is constructive - What will you do if you are the software engineer at google which need to implement the "fake name" feature...

Comment: Not sure there is a 'right' answer unless you snag a g+ or facebook employee :)

Comment: Perhaps there are other clues they use.  For example, all of my fake name/spam accounts have birthdays of January 1.

Comment: Yeah, if they have any automated things, they're worthless. I have numerous fake accounts with names such as "Rusty Shackleford", "Mean Joe Green" and "Tony T. Tiger". Give me a break.

Comment: I think you can have a facebook name as John John, the way facebook does it is by checking if name has weird format, or doesn't have a number or special character or less than 3 characters otherwise its accepted

Comment: You could find books and databases of first and last names. First names are more diverse as people often misspell and invent first names. Last names are much more conformant and can be used as some filtering criteria. We used database of last names with good results, but we didn't have true/false rule, but rather 0-100 scale.

Comment: I wonder what they'd make out of Lyulph Ydwallo Odin Nestor Egbert Lyonel Toedmag Hugh Erchenwyne Saxon Esa Cromwell Orma Nevill Dysart Plantagenet Tollemache-Tollemache. Joking aside, it is a very interesting question in general and is very much a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question really IMHO. Since these are world wide services, then the G+ probably uses heuristics based on the massive amount of data that google has collected on what may be a name.

Comment: Think about it in more general terms, is "How to write an algorithm that filters out fake names?" really not a programming question? What is it then?

Comment: @biziclop I will change the name of the question :)

Comment: @biz - th eonly algo I can think of involves identifying what construes a name. Since a name is any word, possibly not even writable, how can you ever reliably id them, except with heuristics?

Answer (score 1):

It is almost all heuristics. They have a blacklist of names or names they think SOUND fake - ie tied to current events, geography, celebraties etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to determine if a name is fake or real. Facebook and Google+ usually don't delete/disable accounts based on a name like `John John`, that could be a valid name. Google+ started disabling accounts that has `".", "*"` or any other special characters as the only last name or first name ([link](http://www.redmondpie.com/google-suspends-iphone-dev-team-member-and-jailbreak-coder-musclenerd%E2%80%99s-account-on-google/)). There are other instances where account's have been disabled because they are similar to celebrities([link](http://www.blogiversity.org/blogs/willburns1/archive/2010/10/07/i-feel-bad-for-the-35-year-old-man-named-justin-bieber.aspx)).

Alternatively they can ban accounts based on heuristics but I don't think it's enforced in any way. You can create a fake account named `John John` or `Iam Awesome`on facebook and you won't be banned(Source: My friend has a BS account on Facebook for over a year now with an eccentric name and his account is still good.)